# UI Eventhandling by other class

Tags: c#, events

Is it possible to handle events in another class, but the `MainWindow` class, for UI events?

Example:

```
class MainWindow
{
    public Button b;
    //Some Methods
}

class OtherClass
{

   public async someMethod()
   {
      await someTaskToWait();
   }
   public Task someTaskToWait()
   {
      if(...)
      {
        ButtonClickEvent mainWinButton_click = null;
        mainWinButton_click= (_, __)=>
        {
           MainWindow.b.ClickEvent += mainwinButton_click;
        }

          MainWindow.b.ClickEvent -= mainwinButton_click;

      }


   }

}
```

I want to handle the `Button.Click()` Event in the `OtherClass` not `MainWindow`.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have MainWindow's button click event call the mainwinButton_click method in the other class... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register the event handler in the code behind, this would be possible:

```
// Constructor of MainWindow class
public MainWindow()
{
    b.Click+=new OtherClass().mainwinButton_click;
}
```

You could also register from the other class:

```
public class OtherClass
{
    public void RegisterUnregister
    {
        // Reference to main class
        MainWindow ref =...;

        // register event...
        ref.b.Click+=mainwinButton_click;

        // Unregister event...
        ref.b.Click-=mainwinButton_click;
    }
}
```

If your goal is to have event handlers separated into different files, think about using partial classes:

```
// MainWindow.cs
public partial class MainWindow
{
    // your button here
}

// MainWindow.Events.cs
public partial class MainWindow
{
    private void mainwinButton_click(...)
}
```

Comment: My goal is to add and remove my eventhandler from the other class, see the Question, i modified it.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using an `interface` instead.

```
public interface IMainWindowHandler
{
  void ButtonClicked(object sender);
}
```

Then in your `MainWindow` you would store an `IMainWindowHandler` property:

```
public IWindowHandler WindowHandler { get; set; }

...

void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowHandler == null) return;

    this.WindowHandler.ButtonClicked(sender);
}
```

This also lets you 'hot-swap' the handler interface very easily and dynamically.